# PHP Regex - Replace substring within a string

Tags: php, regex

If I have the following string for example:

```
"Value1 *|VALUE_2|* Value3"
```

I want to be able to remove any substrings from within the string that begins with the chracters *| and end in |*.  I will not know what will be between these characters but this is irrelevant as I want to remove whatever is between them.

Basically, I am just unsure of what pattern to use in the code below.

```
preg_replace("*|PATTERN|*", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

`|` is a special character that needs to be escaped in regex:

```
preg_replace('/\|[^|]+\|/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/\|.*\|/U", "", $str);
```

I think this should do the trick..

The `/U` makes the pattern ungreedy so that in `Value1 |VALUE_2| Value3|test` the match will be `|VALUE_2|` instead o `|VALUE_2| Value3|`

If you only want the contents between the |'s removed, you can do:

```
preg_replace("/\|.*\|/U", "||", $str);
```

There are other ways, but this would be the most easy one imho.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  When I posted initially, the * char got removed from the sample so the example should be "Value1 * |VALUE_2| * Value3" and not "Value1 |VALUE_2| Value3".

Comment: I don't think that will make a difference .. `.*` will match anything between the |'s

Comment: @M42's answer was correct in stating that `|` needs to be escaped. Adjusted code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/|[^|]+|/', '', $str);
```

This should do the trick.